# Pulling in Facebook Feed

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, url

Recently, we were using this format to pull an XML feed from Facebook for one of our clients:

```
http://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id={ID HERE}&format=atom10
```

Just today, this seems to not work anymore. I've tried passing in numerous Public Page IDs to this URL, and all of them return an error page from Facebook.

I've searched to see if Facebook has changed this URL structure, or deprecated it, but I can't seem to find anything. Does anyone have any insight into this?

You can follow this link to see an example of the error page I'm getting. I've used CNN's Facebook ID as an example:

http://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=5550296508&format=atom10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The Pages JSON feed (e.g.
>   https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=%2019292868552&format=json)
>   is now deprecated and will stop returning data from Jan 28, 2015
>   onwards. Developers should instead call the feed edge on the Graph
>   API's Page object: /v2.2/{page_id}/feed.

[Source](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog)

Though I can't find a way to access a feed without authentification !
Facebook is becoming more and more liberty killer and is withdrawing into himself !